# Have MathJax Equations activated

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

On other SE sites (such as https://math.stackexchange.com) we have MathJax equations which are a great way to include any sort of formulas in posts, e.g. `$\lambda$` becomes `λ`.

Would it make sense to activate this feature for IOTA SE? Given the underlying framework of IOTA is quite mathematical I feel it'd be a good addition.

Comment: How many questions do we have that would profit from that?

Comment: Lambda is available in any standard character set anyways. (cf. https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/777/theoretical-delay-before-first-approval)

Comment: Lambda really is just a very simplistic example. But looking at https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.05385, you can see that there is a lot of Maths behind IOTA, which could potentially be discussed on SE. And having the tools (i.e. MathJax) would only be a plus. It's not a must, but I don't see the harm in having it (unless there are e.g. costs involved).

Comment: As described in [Helmar's answer](https://iota.meta.stackexchange.com/a/51/69) below, enabling MathJax involves enough resources and performance penalties that we do not generally enable it until there is a *clear* demonstration that it will ***substantially*** benefit the site in actual practice. I'm going to decline this for now, but that doesn't mean it's a done-deal forever. It's just that we should wait to demonstrate a clear *need* for this feature before raising it for further consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I'm running a bit out of comment space I'll use an answer.

There's tons of questions on [Meta.SE about MathJax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=mathjax+is%3Aq). The *problem* if you want to call it is that it's quite dependency heavy and essentially slows down the page to a certain degree. [An analysis shows SO losing a third of a second on every page load](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252283)—and that includes page loads of questions that don't even have formulas in them. Furthermore, that markup would load from the [CF CDN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293237/mathjax-cdn-cdn-mathjax-org-will-be-shutting-down) which means it might not work for those who have firewalls blocking that.

Therefore I'm not convinced that *blindly* enabling MathJax is the way to go. Even without any further configuration Stack Exchange offers the full Unicode set of characters and with html-sub and html-sup quite a bit can be reached.

Personally, I haven't noticed enough questions or answers that would profit from a proper MathJax support at this time. If someone can name a handful of questions or answers that would profit from that however it should be considered.

For now I think we'd profit more from syntax highlighting.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise there was such an overhead. That's very unfortunate.

Comment: Today I wrote [this answer](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/861/what-affects-confirmation-rate-and-how-can-it-be-improved/1818#1818). You can bet I struggled a lot, because I had to embed pictures in my comments whenever I want to use mathematical symbols. Because this was such a pain in the butt, I had to cut out a lot of symbols and formulas. The answer could have been much better and more thorough.

Comment: @Zass that might very well be. Thank for providing it even with the hassle. However, as Robert says, we'll have to make a *clear* demonstration of *substantial* benefit. You're welcome to make that case. Maybe the amount of answers that handle mathy stuff has increased since January.